# WebSphere unable to bind to MQ Queue Connection Factory

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-8

I have WAS 8.5.5.5 and MQ 8.0 running on the same Win7 64-bit laptop.

A queue manager and 2 queues have been set up in MQ.

I've then set up a matching Queue Connection Factory and a Queue in WAS.

The Queue Connection Factory configuration is fine because I was able to test the connection when I set it up.

My problem is that I am unable to retrieve the QueueConnectionFactory through a JNDI call.

I did a nameSpaceDump and I can see these errors:

```
58 (top)/nodes/AU20A9LP0158Node01/servers/server1/jms/CPCPQCF1
58    ERROR: Could not instantiate a bound object.
58    Bound Java type: javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory
58    Local Java type: NULL
58    String representation: 
58    Source object is a javax.naming.Reference.
58       Reference factory class name: com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryFactory
58       RefAddr[0]: Address Type: JCARAAddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 16 6a 61 76 61 78 2e 6e 61 6d 69 6e 67 2e 52 65 66 65 72 65 6e 63 65 ffffffe8 ffffffc6  ...

58       RefAddr[1]: Address Type: ADDR_TYPE_WAS7_WMQRA_CLIENT_CF AddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 11 6a 61 76 61 2e 75 74 69 6c 2e 48 61 73 68 4d 61 70 5 7 ffffffda ffffffc1 ffffffc3 16 60  ...

58       RefAddr[2]: Address Type: JCA AddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 16 6a 61 76 61 78 2e 6e 61 6d 69 6e 67 2e 52 65 66 65 72 65 6e 63 65 ffffffe8 ffffffc6  ...

58       RefAddr[3]: Type: ADDR_TYPE_PROVIDER_HREF 
Content: cells/AU20A9LP0158Node01Cell/nodes/AU20A9LP0158Node01/resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider

58       RefAddr[4]: Address Type: JMS 
AddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 16 6a 61 76 61 78 2e 6e 61 6d 69 6e 67 2e 52 65 66 65 72 65 6e 63 65 ffffffe8 ffffffc6  ...
```

I've checked the Environment Variables in WAS, MQ_INSTALL_ROOT points to ${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/WMQ and this folder contains ra/wmq.jmsra.rar so I assume that's good too.

I've confirmed that wmq.jmsra.rar contains com.ibm.mqjms.jar which in turn contains com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Apart from pointing the Queue Connection Factory to the host and port configured in MQ, I have not changed any of the default settings in WAS.

Is there anything else that needs to be done to get WAS to point to MQ correctly?

Here are screenshots of the Queue Connection Factory in WAS and the Queue Manager in MQ

[Queue Connection Factory in WAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ER0U.png)

[Queue Manager in MQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLFMs.png)

Comment: Can you share the judi lookup call please and the error it gets.  Nite that WAS is pre-installed with the MQ resource adapter so it's not using the one referred to.  The reference is only needed if you are not using a tcp up connection to the queue manager